# Ejecutar función php con pagina con ajax a cada cierto tiempo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

necesito ejecutar una función php (que ejecuta una consulta) cada cierto tiempo, entiendo que es con ajax pero la función tiene que estar en el mismo archivo que la función de ajax que lo va a ejecutar. GRACIAS!

```
<?php
function update(){
//query
}
?>
<script> //ajax que ejecuta funcion </script>
<html>//poner la función php en alguna parte del html para poder llamarla desde ajax </html>
```

Comment: ¿Lo vas a ejecutar en el lado del cliente o del servidor? si es en el lado del cliente es como dices, solo incluye la función ajax como indicas en el código y cada vez que un cliente conecte, lanzará una petición contra el servidor cada cierto tiempo, pero si es en el lado del servidor, debería ser un cron (para entornos gnu/linux).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando tu mismo código, añado la parte que conseguiría llamar la función:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["action"])) { // Se pasa una acción
        switch(sprintf("%d", $_POST["action"]))) { // ¿Qué acción?
            case 1:
                update(); // Llamar a tu función
                echo "Tarea completada!";
                break;
            default:
                echo "Error: Falta una acción";
        }
    }

    function update() {
        //query
    }
?>
```

La parte HTML sería así:

```
<script>
    $(function() { // Ojo! uso jQuery, recuerda añadirla al html
        cron(); // Lanzo cron la primera vez
        function cron() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "index.php", // Podrías separar las funciones de PHP en un fichero a parte
                data: {
                    action: 1
                }
            }).done(function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            });
        }
        setInterval(function() {
            cron();
        }, 10000); // Lanzará la petición cada 10 segundos
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podés usar una función llamada [**setInterval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) de JavaScript.

Ejemplo:

```
timer = setInterval("update()", 5000);
```

Eso va a ejecutar tu función `update` cada 5 segundos

En `update` realizas la llamada a tu archivo.php.

Comment: Fíjate que la función que quiere ejecutar es parte de php, por lo que no puedes llamar la función directamente y tienes que usar ajax.

Comment: gracias, en por eso explique que en update realizas la llamada ajax. me equivoco al respecto?

Comment: Te pongo un ejemplo en la respuesta, se podría mejorar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir un "throttle" a tu función:

```
function throttle(f, delay){
var timer = null;
  return function(){
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
        f.apply(context, args);
    },
    delay || 750);
  };
}
```

En los argumentos que acepta esta función pondrías el nombre de tu función y el tiempo en milisegundos de retraso en la ejecución. Mas o menos así:

```
throttle(miFuncion(), 10000);
```